# Are $[[n,k,d]]$ quantum error correction codes linear?

Tags: error-correction

I am familiar with traditional coding theory. And I do realize that the error mechanisms in quantum processes are different.

The question [What does quantum error correction code notation stand for?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/what-does-quantum-error-correction-code-notation-stand-for) and its answers are helpful. However I have the queries below:

1. Are $[[n,k,d]]$ quantum codes linear? In another question, someone told the OP to look up codetables.de which has a listing of classical linear codes. The suggestion was, find $[n,k,d]$ related information there and use it for quantum codes.
2. Are quantum error correction codes always systematic? I would guess so. Or in other words, do we always need to know what are the "data qubits" and what are "check qubits"?
3. What's a good tutorial introduction to quantum error correction, for someone with extensive classical error correction background, both in algebraic coding theory and information theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the website has tables for both classical *and* quantum codes; look more carefully (QECC in left column). $[[n,k,d]]$ is notation for linear codes.
2. You can put the generators in many forms; there are standard forms analogous to systematic case in classical; as in classical case you don't need to distinguish between "data" and "parity" if you don't want to.
3. This book might be a good choice :
   [Quantum Information ...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780128219829/quantum-information-processing-quantum-computing-and-quantum-error-correction)